# How to excute Fortran program in python for multiple input

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a Fortran program and want to execute it in python for multiple files. I have 2000 input files but in my Fortran code I am able to run only one file at a time. How should I call the Fortran program in python?

**My Script:**

```
import subprocess
import glob
input = glob.glob('C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Fortran_Program_Rum/*.txt')
output = glob.glob('C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Fortran_Program_Rum/Output/')
f = open("output", "w")
for i in input:
    subprocess.Popen(["FORTRAN ~/C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Fortran_Program_Rum/phase1.f", "--domain "+i])
f.write(i)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 2, in <module>
subprocess.Popen(["FORTRAN ~/C:/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/Fortran_Program_Rum/phase1.f", "--domain "+i])
  File "C:\Users\Vishnu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Vishnu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps calling the fortran program with `subprocess` a la this thread?

[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

e.g.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('fortran program.f', '-flags')
```

also, [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: Can you please explain with code? I am not much familiar with python

Comment: I am not able to run fortran program for multiple input file, can you please guide me ?

Comment: I have edit my question, please check once and guide me

Comment: well, reading your error message, the path to your file has not been properly specified as it can't be found..

Comment: I have check given path but it is ok, can you check once my code Is it correct? please guide me dear